# Variables losing their value

Tags: mysql, database, vbscript, adodb, mysql-odbc-connector

I have the following vbscript code:

```
hemisphereConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
                             "Server=" & hemisphereServer & ";" & _
                             "Database=" & hemisphereDatabase & ";" & _
                             "User=" & hemisphereUsername & ";" & _
                             "Password=" & hemispherePassword & ";"

Set hemisphereConnection = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
hemisphereConnection.Open(hemisphereConnectionString)

hem_sql = "SELECT * FROM hei_vision_update WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM hei_vision_update WHERE done = 'N' GROUP BY name)"

Set hemisphereResult = hemisphereConnection.Execute(hem_sql)

if hemisphereResult.EOF = false then
    hemisphereResult.MoveFirst()
end if
msgbox isnull(hemisphereResult("home_publish").value)
msgbox hemisphereResult("home_publish").value
```

It is part of a much larger script (too big to post here but these are the key lines)
My message boxes display false (ie the field has a value that is not null) and the next message box crashes saying "Invalid use of Null"

Anyone have any Ideas??

I have modified my code to the above, This is all of it (except the server and password details). There are no OERN/OEG0 lines now. The row I am getting from the database has a 'Y' in the home_publish field, hence the first message box displaying false is correct. Just the second one displaying "Invalid use of Null" is the mystery. I am beginning to wonder if there is an issue with the MySQL Driver?

Now this is getting silly:

I changed the last 2 lines to these 3:

```
msgbox hemisphereResult("home_publish").value
msgbox isnull(hemisphereResult("home_publish").value)
msgbox hemisphereResult("home_publish").value
```

The first message box displays my value 'Y'.
Now the second message box displays true (which it obviously isn't).
And finally my third message box gives my "Invalid use of null" error.

Anyone else ever experienced variables losing their value just because you have used them?

Comment: You SELECT home_phone, but you try to display the field home_publish; get rid of your global OERN.

Comment: Sorry, I hacked all the other fields out of my selection because it would have been to long to post but home_publish is there (as well as home_phone!) - What is a Global OERN?

Comment: OK, So OERN is On Error Resume Next. Didn't help though. If I have it on it just skips the error

Comment: Try `MsgBox TypeName(hemisphereResult("home_publish").Value)`.

Comment: I added the line twice:  
    msgbox TypeName(hemisphereResult("home_publish").Value)  
    msgbox TypeName(hemisphereResult("home_publish").Value)  
the first message box says "String", The second says Null.  
Somehow my field is destroyed on first use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `hemisphereResult` is `ADODB.Recordset`, then `hemisphereResult("home_publish")` is `ADODB.Field`, at which point the following happens.

`IsNull` does not try to further investigate the passed object and returns `False` because the field itself exists as an object in the recordset.

`MsgBox`, on contrary, cannot do a meaningful thing to an object, so it calls the default property of that object (the `Field` object) in order to display it. The default property is `.Value`, and *that* is `Null`.

So despite the arguments to `IsNull` and `MsgBox` look the same in code, they are not actually the same.

You might want to be explicit in your demands:

```
msgbox isnull(hemisphereResult("home_publish").value)
```

---

While the above is true, you might have been affected by a MySQL bug too ([44831](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44831), [42385](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42385) etc.)

The suggested workaround is to use client-side cursor:

```vb
set hemisphereResult = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
hemisphereResult.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
hemisphereResult.open "select ...", hemisphereConnection
```

Comment: Thanks for the response GSerg
I switched the code to:
    msgbox isnull(hemisphereResult("home_publish").value)
    msgbox hemisphereResult("home_publish").value
But still get exactly the same result.
Also, from the database, the field does have a value of "Y"

Comment: @user2530030 Does the amended `IsNull` still give `False`? It should give `True` instead, but the `MsgBox` should indeed fail because it won't display a `Null`.

Comment: Definitely still gives False! And it should give false, because the field in the database does have a value. but still crashes on the second msgbox saying "Invalid use of null"

Comment: @AngusWalker Do you have VB6 or MS Office where you could paste that code and see in watch windows how `hemisphereResult` values change at runtime?

Comment: Loaded it into Access and queried the fields as they are processed in the immediate window. Just confirms what we already know. as soon as the fields are queried, they dissapear!

Comment: I got around it by puting the value in another variable on first use, then using that. However, I've just tested your method and it works perfectly. I am switching to your method as there are many fields I am using and hence I had to dim a lot of variables that are no longer required.  Thank you so much for your help.